# Does this code break MVVM?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

Building my first project with MVVM, I would like to know if the following code breaks the model.

The aim of the command is to switch between two UserControls (ucDrumStandard and ucDrumStandardList. Both share the same viewmodel.
This viewmodel inherits from a viewmodelbase containing the "ParentContext".
UserControls are 'stored' in ParentContext.listOfViews.

(Apologize for my VB Code ;-)

```
#Region "CmdSwitchDrumStandardView"

Public ReadOnly Property CmdSwitchDrumStandardView() As ICommand
    Get
        If _cmdSwitchDrumStandardView Is Nothing Then
            _cmdSwitchDrumStandardView = New RelayCommand(AddressOf SwitchDrumStandardView)

        End If
        Return _cmdSwitchDrumStandardView
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub SwitchDrumStandardView()

    ' There are  two views(ucDrumStandard and ucDrumStandardList) for the same viewmodel 

    If ParentContext.CurrentView.Uid = "ucDrumStandard" Then

        ' switch to ucDrumStandardGrid

        If ParentContext.ListOfViews.ContainsKey("ucDrumStandardGrid") Then

            ParentContext.CurrentView = (From obj As KeyValuePair(Of String, UIElement) In ParentContext.ListOfViews
                                    Where obj.Key = "ucDrumStandardGrid"
                                    Select obj.Value).FirstOrDefault
        Else

            Dim m_ucDrumStandardGrid = New ucDrumStandardGrid


            ParentContext.ListOfViews.Add("ucDrumStandardGrid", m_ucDrumStandardGrid)
            ParentContext.CurrentView = m_ucDrumStandardGrid

        End If

    ElseIf ParentContext.CurrentView.Uid = "ucDrumStandardGrid" Then

        ' switch to ucDrumStandard

        If ParentContext.ListOfViews.ContainsKey("ucDrumStandard") Then

            ParentContext.CurrentView = (From obj As KeyValuePair(Of String, UIElement) In ParentContext.ListOfViews
                                    Where obj.Key = "ucDrumStandard"
                                    Select obj.Value).FirstOrDefault
        Else

            Dim m_ucDrumStandard = New ucDrumStandard

            ParentContext.ListOfViews.Add("ucDrumStandard", m_ucDrumStandard)
            ParentContext.CurrentView = m_ucDrumStandard

        End If

    End If

End Sub

#End Region
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the MVVM pattern the communication between the ViewModel & View layers should be done only by Binding & Commands. ViewModel code shouldn't use FrameworkElements so yes, your code "break" the MVVM pattern.

Your ParentContext which I assume is a ViewModel class should have a CurrentView property that's of type of the ViewModel layer of the "Page" objects.

The render of those ViewModel objects in the View layer should be done using DataTemplate & Bindings. I'll add a little sample illustrating all this.

//ViewModel

```
public class AppVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    //your code...

    private PageVM _currentView;
    public PageVM CurrentView {
        get {return _currentView;}
        set {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
}

public class PageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    //your "view" data visible in the UI
}
```

//XAML

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ucDrumStandardVM}">
            <ucDrumStandard/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ucDrumStandardListVM}">
            <ucDrumStandardList/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

If you really want to keep the same ViewModel object for your two "pages" then you have to use a Trigger

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView.Uid, Mode=OneWay}" Value="ucDrumStandard">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ucDrumStandard/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView.Uid, Mode=OneWay}" Value="ucDrumStandardGrid">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ucDrumStandardList/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: You say : Your ParentContext which I assume is a ViewModel class should have a CurrentView property that's of type of the ViewModel layer of the "Page" objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a CurrentView property in the main ViewModel. In the XMAL of my main page I have :      <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" x:Name="MainContent"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="60,1,2,2" />  Anyway I have to determine and set the value of CurrentView. My question is now, how do I do this ? I was thinking that maybe I need a sort of controler ?

Comment: Indeed you have a CurrentView property but it seems to be of UIElement type instead of the Viewmodel type of your two "pages". The value of your CurrentView will be set either by a Command (example a button "switch to page x") or by a Viewmodel object. Sorry i'm on my phone ;)